# Next.js Image- how to maintain aspect ratio and add letterboxes when needed

Tags: css, next.js

I have an area of my Next.js app which is the selected photo of a photo gallery so it has to stay fixed in size as people flip through the selected image or a photo is loading. I have a responsive layout but if really pressed, I'd say that this pixel area is 566px*425px.

I'm confused about how to actually do this. Here's the closest I've been able to get it, but the problem is that I get overflow of the image when the aspect ratio exceeds 566x425 and for images that have an aspect ratio below 566x425 it will stretch it in the Y direct. What I really want is to have a fixed box and then if the aspect ratios differ from the max size, you'll see letterboxes either along the sides or on the top and bottom.

```
           <div
            style={{
              position: 'relative',
              width: '566px',
              height: '425px',
            }}
          >
            <Image
              src={currCommit.image.url}
              alt="Current Image"
              layout={'fill'}
              objectFit="cover"
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 41):

Ooh I got it! The key was to set the parent div to a fixed size and relative and then set the `Image` to a layout of fill and an objectFit of contain. The only downside to this approach is I need to set media queries so it will scale for smaller sizes.

```
<div className="relative item-detail">
  <Image src={currCommit.image.url} alt="Current Image" layout={'fill'} objectFit={'contain'} />
</div>
```

Then in the css I set:

```
.item-detail {
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
}
```

Comment: There's one more downside - broken border-radius. But anyway it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: this is horrible. It will load an image the size of the viewport

Comment: @martin sounds like you forgot to add `position: relative` to the parent since the Image is `absolute`, you have to do that because the element with `position: absolute` will look for the closest parent with relative position

Comment: @Coherent What if I don't want to specify or don't know e.g. the width of the image? For example, if I have multiple images that share the same height but not the same width. How do I automatically assign a width to maintain the aspect ratio? I tried `width: auto` and `width: fit-content` but no luck.

Answer (score 15):

there's better solution i think, `NextImage` have callback property [onLoadingComplete](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#onloadingcomplete):

> A callback function that is invoked once the image is completely loaded and the placeholder has been removed.

> The onLoadingComplete function accepts one parameter, an object with the following properties: naturalWidth, naturalHeight

you can use the natural properties to set image ratio without loosing NextImage's `layout` functionality like this:

```js
const NaturalImage = (props: ImageProps) => {
  const [ratio, setRatio] = useState(16/9) // default to 16:9

  return (
    <NextImage
      {...props}
      // set the dimension (affected by layout)
      width={200}
      height={200 / ratio}
      layout="fixed" // you can use "responsive", "fill" or the default "intrinsic"
      onLoadingComplete={({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) => 
        setRatio(naturalWidth / naturalHeight)
      }
    />
  )
}
```

the only downside is the aspect ratio applied only after image loaded, so the placeholder using the default ratio (in this case 16:9 - common), and this can cause [CLS](https://web.dev/cls/)

Answer (score 10):

Next13 onwards, layout and objectFit have been [deprecated](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-upgrade-to-13) in favour of intrinsic style properties. This actually makes our job easier as you can now style the image with regular CSS, like so:

```
import Image from "next/image";

<div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '566px', height: '425px'}}>
    <Image fill 
        src={currCommit.image.url}
        alt="Current Image" 
        style={{objectFit: 'cover'}}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: width is required field in Next Image

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use state for this.  Using the below, the image's width will scale to the container and hold its aspect ratio. Make sure to set the height and width props to the max size that image would be.

**Jan 2024 update via the NextJs 14 docs**

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
 
export default function Page({ photoUrl }) {
  return (
    <Image
      src={photoUrl}
      alt="Picture of the author"
      sizes="100vw"
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: 'auto',
      }}
      width={500}
      height={300}
    />
  )
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#responsive-images

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that I could find that does not require to specify exact width or height.

```html
<Image
  layout="responsive"
  width="100%"
  height="62.5%" // 16:10 aspect ratio
  objectFit="cover"
  src={src}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [bayu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7914206/bayu) asnwer,
You can create a custom component called `RatioNextImage` and use it like.

```
<RatioNextImage src={put_your_URL_here} alt={put_the_alt_here}/>
```

In `RatioNextImage.tsx`

```
import NextImage from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
}

const RatioNextImage = ({ src, alt }: Props) => {
  const [ratio, setRatio] = useState(16 / 9); // this value can be anything by default, could be 1 if you want a square
  return (
    <NextImage
      src={src}
      width={200}
      height={200 / ratio}
      layout="fixed"
      onLoadingComplete={({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) => {
        setRatio(naturalWidth / naturalHeight);
      }}
    />
  );
};
export default RatioNextImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since '**objectFit**' has been deprecated with latest versions of Next, here is a snippet that works well:

```
 <div className="relative w-10 h-10">
      <Image src={User} alt="User Profile Image" fill />
 </div>
```

**w-10, h-10** being CSS classes that define width and height values.

Hope this helps